# Object Oriented design for a live auction taking in bidders

Tags: java, object-oriented

My goal is to design an Auction that will take in data like this:

```
Bidder A - ( StartingBid , AutoIncrement , MaxBid)

Bidder B - ( StartingBid , AutoIncrement , MaxBid)
```

This Auction will generate a winner based on the bidders entered. The Auction algorithm will automatically increment a bidder's starting bid given he has a relative losing position to other Bidders. However, the algorithm should never increment a user's bid automatically if the max bid would be surpassed!

Here is my design. These are all the classes I created. Please let  me know If there is a  better  object oriented  design.

```
   /**
 * Auction will have a list of bidders where order matters in tie disputes
 * 
 * @author agoel
 *
 */
public class Auction {

    private boolean isLive = true;
    private List<Bidder> bidders;
    private String itemName;
    private Bidder winner;

    public Auction(List<Bidder> bidders, String itemName) {
    this.bidders = bidders;
    }

    public boolean isLive() {
    return isLive;
    }

    public void setLive(boolean isLive) {
    this.isLive = isLive;
    }

    public List<Bidder> getBidders() {
    return bidders;
    }

    public void setBidders(List<Bidder> bidders) {
    this.bidders = bidders;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
    return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
    this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    public Bidder findWinner() {

    Collections.sort(bidders);
    Map.Entry<Bidder, Double> winningEntry = processBids();

    Bidder winningBidder = null;
    winningBidder = winningEntry.getKey();
    winningBidder.setCurrentAmount(winningEntry.getValue());
    return winningBidder;

    }

    /**
     * Main Processing which increments bids based on if they have capacity and
     * if the currentAmount < max bid If there is a current tie where both bids
     * are equal to the max then we break that by checking a list that gets
     * populated when a tie occurs
     * 
     * A bid is marked as a loser if it no longer has capacity to increase its
     * bid and its less than the current max bid
     * 
     * @param validBids
     * @param max
     * @return
     */
    private Map.Entry<Bidder, Double> processBids() {

    HashMap<Bidder, Double> maxBids = new HashMap<Bidder, Double>();

    for (Bidder participant : bidders) {

        double maxMinusInitial = participant.getMaxBid() - participant.getCurrentAmount();

        if (maxMinusInitial % participant.getAutoIncrement() == 0) {
        maxBids.put(participant, participant.getMaxBid());
        } else {
        maxBids.put(participant, participant.getMaxBid() - (maxMinusInitial % participant.getAutoIncrement()));
        }
    }

    // Create a list from elements of HashMap
    List<Map.Entry<Bidder, Double>> list = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<Bidder, Double>>(maxBids.entrySet());

    // Sort the list
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<Bidder, Double>>() {
        public int compare(Map.Entry<Bidder, Double> o1, Map.Entry<Bidder, Double> o2) {
        return (o1.getValue()).compareTo(o2.getValue());
        }
    });

    Map.Entry<Bidder, Double> winningEntry = list.get(list.size() - 1);
    Bidder winningBidder = winningEntry.getKey();
    Map.Entry<Bidder, Double> secondPlaceEntry = list.get(list.size() - 2);

    // Resolve Ties
    boolean ties = resolveTies(winningEntry, secondPlaceEntry);

    if (ties) {
        return determineByPositionInAuction(winningEntry, secondPlaceEntry);
    }

    double secondPlaceMaxBet = secondPlaceEntry.getValue();

    double maxMinusInitial = secondPlaceMaxBet - winningEntry.getKey().getCurrentAmount();

    if (maxMinusInitial % winningEntry.getKey().getAutoIncrement() == 0) {

        winningEntry.setValue(secondPlaceMaxBet + winningBidder.getAutoIncrement());
    } else {
        double remainder = secondPlaceMaxBet % winningBidder.getAutoIncrement();
        secondPlaceMaxBet = secondPlaceMaxBet + remainder;
        winningEntry.setValue(secondPlaceMaxBet);

    }

    return winningEntry;

    }

    private Map.Entry<Bidder, Double> determineByPositionInAuction(Entry<Bidder, Double> winningEntry,
        Entry<Bidder, Double> secondPlaceEntry) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Bidder secondPlace = secondPlaceEntry.getKey();
    Bidder firstPlace = winningEntry.getKey();

    if (firstPlace.getPositionInAuction() > secondPlace.getPositionInAuction()) {
        return secondPlaceEntry;
    } else {
        return winningEntry;
    }

    }

    private boolean resolveTies(Entry<Bidder, Double> winningEntry, Entry<Bidder, Double> secondPlaceEntry) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method st

    if (winningEntry.getValue().equals(secondPlaceEntry.getValue())) {

        return true;

    }

    return false;

    }

    public Bidder getWinner() {
    return winner;
    }

    public void setWinner(Bidder winner) {
    this.winner = winner;
    }

}
 public final class AuctionResult {

   private Bidder winningBidder; 

    public AuctionResult(Bidder winningBidder) {
     this.winningBidder = winningBidder;
    }   

    /**
     * Display the Auction  Result 
     */
    public void displayResults() {

    System.out.println("The auction c  was won by " + winningBidder.getName()  + " for the amount of $ " + winningBidder.getCurrentAmount());

    }

    public double getWinningAmount() {
    return winningBidder.getCurrentAmount();
    }

}


/**
 * A bidder will have a one to one association with a bid object.
 * 
 * @author agoel
 *
 */
public class Bidder implements Comparable<Bidder> {

    private double maxBid;
    private boolean loser;

    private String name;

    private double autoIncrement;

    private double currentAmount;

    private int positionInAuction;

    public Bidder(double currentAmount, double maxBid, String name, double autoIncrement , int positionInAuction) {
    this.maxBid = maxBid;
    this.currentAmount = currentAmount;
    this.setAutoIncrement(autoIncrement);
    this.name = name;
    this.positionInAuction = positionInAuction;
    }

    public double getMaxBid() {
    return maxBid;
    }

    public void setMaxBid(double maxBid) {
    this.maxBid = maxBid;
    }

    public String getName() {
    return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }

    public double getAutoIncrement() {
    return autoIncrement;
    }

    public void setAutoIncrement(double autoIncrement) {
    this.autoIncrement = autoIncrement;
    }

    public int getPositionInAuction() {
    return positionInAuction;
    }

    public void setPositionInAuction(int positionInAuction) {
    this.positionInAuction = positionInAuction;
    }

    public double getCurrentAmount() {
    return currentAmount;
    }

    public void setCurrentAmount(double currentAmount) {
    this.currentAmount = currentAmount;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Bidder otherBid) {

    if (this.currentAmount < otherBid.getCurrentAmount()) {
        return -1;
    }

    else if (this.currentAmount == otherBid.getCurrentAmount()) {
        return 0;
    }

    else {
        return 1;
    }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

    return Double.valueOf(currentAmount).hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object otherBid) {

    if (otherBid == this) {
        return true;
    }

    if (!(otherBid instanceof Bidder)) {
        return false;
    }

    Bidder bid = (Bidder) otherBid;

    if (this.currentAmount == bid.getCurrentAmount()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;

    }

    public boolean isLoser() {
    return loser;
    }

    public void setLoser(boolean loser) {
    this.loser = loser;
    }

}

import java.util.List;

import com.goel.model.Auction;
import com.goel.model.Bidder;

public class AuctionBuilder {
    /**
     * Realistically an Auction should be built by pieces
     * @param bidders
     * @param itemName
     * @return
     */
    public Auction buildAuction(List<Bidder> bidders, String itemName) {

    return new Auction(bidders, itemName);

    }

}

import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Set;

    import com.goel.model.Auction;
    import com.goel.model.AuctionResult;
    import com.goel.model.Bidder;

    /**
     * This class will handle the heavylighting and be a facade to the backend. It
     * will operate on an Auction object 
     * result in an immutable class on completion of the Auction
     * 
     * @author agoel
     *
     */
    public class AuctionProcessor {

        private Auction auction;

        public Auction getAuction() {
        return auction;
        }

        public void setAuction(Auction auction) {
        this.auction = auction;
        }


        public AuctionProcessor(Auction auction) {
        this.auction = auction;
        }

        public AuctionResult execute() {

        Bidder winningBidder = auction.findWinner();

        return new AuctionResult(winningBidder);

        }



    }


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.goel.model.Auction;
import com.goel.model.AuctionResult;
import com.goel.model.Bidder;

public class AuctionCoordinator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    AuctionBuilder auctionBuilder = new AuctionBuilder();
    Bidder linda = new Bidder(170.0d, 240.0d, "Linda", 3.0d, 1);
    Bidder dave = new Bidder(160.0d, 243.0d, "Dave", 7.0d, 2);
    Bidder eric = new Bidder(190.0d, 240.0d, "Matt", 4.0d, 3);

    List<Bidder> bidders = new ArrayList<Bidder>();
    bidders.add(linda);
    bidders.add(dave);
    bidders.add(eric);

    Auction auction = auctionBuilder.buildAuction(bidders, "Record  Player");
    AuctionProcessor processor = new AuctionProcessor(auction);
    AuctionResult result = processor.execute();

    result.displayResults();

    }

}
```

Comment: Is this just a design or does it actually do something? Did you test whether it works?

Comment: Yeah if you look at AuctionCoordinator class  it builds an Auction  and  passes it to the AuctionProcessor which executes and returns an AuctionResult